# If Scroll Past 300vh

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure if this is possible or not?

I know how to show and hide a class after a specified pixel height, but not a viewport height? Specifically 3x the viewport height?

Fixed Pixel Value (Shows and Hides) for 300px. Hides the div after 300px of scrolling, reverts it back when the value is less than 300px.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 300) {
    $('.para-hide').hide();
} else {
    $('.para-hide').show();
}
```

I want to do the exact same thing, but with a value of 300vh (3 times the viewport height).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the viewport height & do math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`300vh` is just `$(window).height()` times three, so you can just use that:

```
if (scroll >= (3 * $(window).height())) {
  $('.para-hide').hide();
} else {
  $(.'para-hide').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHeight` field of `window` object:

```
if (scroll >= window.innerHeight * 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `document.documentElement.clientHeight`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
if (scroll >= 3*h) {
    $('.para-hide').hide();
} else {
    $('.para-hide').show();
}
```

Or with jQuery, simply use `$(window).height()`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var h = $(window).height();
if (scroll >= 3*h) {
    $('.para-hide').hide();
} else {
    $('.para-hide').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 100vh in jQuery: `$(window).height()`

#### 100vh in Pure JS: `window.innerHeight`

So `300vh` will be `$(window).height() * 3` (jQuery)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var maxH = $(window).height() * 3;
  if (scroll >= maxH) {
    $('.para-hide').hide();
  } else {
    $('.para-hide').show();
  }

});
```